# azure devops python twine update failed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, twine

I try to create a build pipeline for uploading my python package to an Azure DevOps Artifact Feed. With my default feed it works fine by using this yaml

```
- script: |
    python setup.py sdist
  displayName: 'Make sdist'

- script: |
    python setup.py bdist_wheel --universal
  displayName: 'Make wheel'




- task: TwineAuthenticate@1 
  inputs:
    artifactFeed: christophhaene

- script: |
    cat $(PYPIRC_PATH) 
  displayName: 'see file'  

- script: |
    python -m twine upload -r 'christophhaene' --config-file $(PYPIRC_PATH) dist/* --verbose
```

Now I would like to change the feed. For that, I created a new feed in a DevOps projekts calls sftp with the name sftp. If I now change the yaml like that:

```
- task: TwineAuthenticate@1 
  inputs:
    artifactFeed: sftp

- script: |
    python -m twine upload -r 'sftp' --config-file $(PYPIRC_PATH) dist/* --verbose
```

I get the following error code in the twine upload section:

```
[command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /home/vsts/work/_temp/d8fc4191-edad-4b2c-9393-3e3ddbf716f2.sh
Uploading distributions to https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/christophhaene/_packaging/sftp/pypi/upload
Uploading sftp-0.1.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl

  0%|          | 0.00/4.43k [00:00<?, ?B/s]
100%|██████████| 4.43k/4.43k [00:00<00:00, 49.8kB/s]HTTPError: 404 Client Error: Not Found - The feed with ID 'sftp' doesn't exist. (DevOps Activity ID: B2DC0264-1FC0-460B-849E-3D77F371E984) for url: https://pkgs.dev.azure.com/christophhaene/_packaging/sftp/pypi/upload

Content received from server:
{"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"The feed with ID 'sftp' doesn't exist.","typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Feed.WebApi.FeedIdNotFoundException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Feed.WebApi","typeKey":"FeedIdNotFoundException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
##[error]Bash exited with code '1'.
```

Any idea?

Many thanks
Christoph

Comment: When you edit the YAML in azure devops and you try to add a new twine task, in the right side you have an helper with the tasks, choose there task, can you see your feed in the drop down list?

Answer (score 0):

This should be the issue on our side. I have checked and the feed `sftp` **exists** in your org `christ***ene`.

Also, after check the corresponding log by using the **activity id** you provided, the feed access URL the server used is very abnormal: `*****/Ade41224c-3ad6-*****-5f24cb2da86a/_apis/Packaging/Feeds/sftp`.

As normal, the api that used to get feed, should be consists of `{org name/id}/apis/packaging/Feeds/{feed name/id}`. BUT, this id `Ade41224c-3ad6-*****-5f24cb2da86a` is not the one of this org(`christ***ene`) id, but your collection/account id. This cause this feed access failed.

---

Please go our [official community](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/post.html?space=21) to raise this issue ticket. Then we could involve our product group to handle this issue. When you raise the ticket, please also share your *org name, project name and the pipeline definition name* with that(for security, please share it in the comment by selecting **Viewed by Microsoft only**). Also, do not miss this `activity id` which is very important to check log from backend.

Comment: If you don't mind, you could share your ticket link here. Then I can contact the corresponding engineer to describe and work with that ticket.